# How to find a cell from another sheet using multiple criterias with dates

Tags: excel, match, criteria

I have the following example of data:

I need to know how can i find the column sys_respnum and transfer that to the 2nd set of data knowing that the dates and times of the first set of data are between the dates and times (but never equal) of the second set of data, and that the IP address should be equal.

I've tried combining dates and IP addresses and do a vlookup but without results. I also have a set of data where i can confirm that the formula for this is working.

Thank you.

Editing for clarification:

[image: Dataset1]

[image: Dataset2]

I've marked the expected result in yellow.

Comment: Based on the sample data, what is the expected result? The dates don't overlap at all. The only thing in common between the two data sets is the one IP address. Please provide a data sample that actually works with your description and mock up the desired result. Edit your question to do that. Do NOT post clarifications in a comment. Post a comment when you have edited your question, so people following it will get alerted.

Comment: I have edited the question to show more correct examples. Thank you.

Comment: Sorry, you've lost me. What is the connection between the yellow highlight and the question? What data do you want to get from where? The second screenshot looks like you've only removed the IP column. What is your question???